# Different background color depending on property status

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

I have a problem with styling, which I'm struggling a lot with. On my website, I need to set different background colours per each property status. For example 'Under Offer' should be blue, and 'For Rent' green (like in the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFGBa.png).

My website address is http://horizons-estateagents.co.uk

I would really appreciate your help, as I was trying different things and didn't get any result.

Thank you very much.
Anna

EDIT:

```
<figcaption>
                    <?php
                    $status_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,"property-status" );
                    if(!empty( $status_terms )){
                        $status_count = 0;
                        foreach( $status_terms as $term ){
                            if( $status_count > 0 ){
                                echo ', ';
                            }
                            echo $term->name;
                            $status_count++;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </figcaption>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unique class names for the parent or the particular element. Using that, you can assign unique background color for the element.

Comment: Do you mean just like in the answer below by Praveen Kumar?

Comment: And where should I add them? :)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP Code, do this:

```
<figcaption<?php
switch ($status)
{
  case "For Rent":
    echo ' class="rent"';
    break;
  case "Under Offer":
    echo ' class="offer"';
    break;
  case "Rental Agreed":
    echo ' class="agreed"';
    break;
}
?>><?php // ?></figcaption>
```

And now in CSS:

```css
.rent {background-color: #ccf;}
.offer {background-color: #cfc;}
.agreed {background-color: #fcc;}
```

---

Anyways, here you go. Find this:

```
<figcaption>
    <?php
```

Replace with:

```
<figcaption<?php
$status = get_the_terms( $post->ID,"property-status" );
switch ($status)
    {
      case "For Rent":
        echo ' class="rent"';
        break;
      case "Under Offer":
        echo ' class="offer"';
        break;
      case "Rental Agreed":
        echo ' class="agreed"';
        break;
    }
?>>
    <?php
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Should I place the PHP code in theme's functions.php?

Comment: @AnnaSancewicz Yes. You have to.

Comment: Wherever you have `<figcaption>`, replace it there.

Comment: I found it in property-children.php and it looks like this at the moment: http://i.imgur.com/3XoIA3i.png . Should I replace it all, what's in the frame?

Comment: @AnnaSancewicz Can you please copy and paste the contents of the red block to the question, please?

Comment: @AnnaSancewicz Check out the solution!

Comment: I included the code in the question. Again thank you very much for your kind help, Praveen :)

Comment: @AnnaSancewicz I have updated the answer, Kindly check it out.

Comment: Thank you Praveen - I have made the changes exactly how you asked me to and nothing changed.. I don't know why, as your solution looks very logical. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you again :))